# What is the asymptotic version of the solid angle formula in $d$ dimensions?

Tags: functions, euclidean-geometry, factorial, gamma-function, solid-angle

It is well known that the **solid angle** in an euclidian space of $d$ dimensions ($d = 2 n$ or $d = 2 n + 1$, where $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots, \infty$) is given by these formulae:
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\Omega_{2 n} &= \frac{1}{(n - 1)!} \, 2 \pi^n, \qquad
&\Omega_{2 n + 1} &= \frac{2^{2 n} \, n!}{(2 n)!} \, 2 \pi^n.
\end{align}
For examples: $\Omega_1 = 2$, $\Omega_2 = 2 \pi$, $\Omega_3 = 4 \pi$, $\Omega_4 = 2 \pi^2$.  Oddly, these formulae have a maximum value for $d = 7$:
$$\tag{2}
\Omega_7 = \frac{16 \pi^3}{15},
$$
and $\Omega_d \rightarrow 0$ when $d \rightarrow \infty$.  We could also use the **Gamma** function $\Gamma(n)$ to get a smooth version of (1), instead of a discrete one, and plot some nice graphics with *Mathematica*:
$$\tag{3}
\Omega(d) = \frac{2 \sqrt{\pi}^d}{\Gamma(d/2)}.
$$
My question is simple:

What is the simplest asymptotic version of (1) or (3), for very large values of $d$?

I tried using the Stirling formula into (3) but I'm not getting a good result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, the Asymptotic function of *Mathematica* gave me this expression for large $d$:
$$
\Omega(d) \approx \frac{1}{6} \, \frac{6 d - 1}{\sqrt{\pi d}} \, \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi e}{d}}^{\, d} \approx \sqrt{\frac{d}{\pi}} \, \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi e}{d}}^{\, d}.
$$
This appears to be what I'm looking for.